# ETag and If-None-Match HTTP Headers are not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, etag, if-none-match

I have a file in my *webserver* and I am downloading that to my app everytime I access it because its possible that file content might be changed But If it is changed I would like to download that time only so bandwidth can be saved and fortunately that's what this **ETag** and **If-None-Match** *header fields* are for.

- When I make a request first time ,I retrieve the *ETag* from the HTTP response headers

[image: First time request to the file]

- In the subsequent requests to download that file I'd attach the *Etag* value for *If-None-Match* headerfield so that if there is no change then I'd get HTTP response status code 304 or else I'd get 200 if there is a change in the file.

  [image: Second time request for same file]

*Note:*

When I try the above steps in **Advanced REST Client Application** in chrome it works fine as it is supposed to be but when I try that in iOS I always get the response code 200 but it should have given me 304 for the subsequent requests.

Here is the sample code I use

```
var request1 =  NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: "http://10.12.1.101/Etag/ringtone1.mp3")!)
let Etagvalue="\"36170-52c1cc36d9b40\""
var session1 = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request1.HTTPMethod = "GET"
var err: NSError?
request1.addValue(Etagvalue, forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")

var task = session1.dataTaskWithRequest(request1, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
       print("response: \(response)")

})
```

Here is the response

> response: Optional( { URL:
>   http://10.12.1.101/Etag/ringtone1.mp3 } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 221552;
>       "Content-Type" = "audio/mpeg";
>       Date = "Wed, 24 Feb 2016 14:57:53 GMT";
>       Etag = "\"36170-52c1cc36d9b40\"";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
>       "Last-Modified" = "Fri, 19 Feb 2016 10:15:33 GMT";
>       Server = "Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.29"; } })

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: show us the request generated. e.g. using a proxy server (e.g. charles)

Comment: @Daij-Djan - All of a sudden it started working ! I couldn't guess why this inconsistency !

Comment: @Daij-Djan - is there any dependency for E-tag to work other than ..server side configuration ? My fingers are still crossed how come it started working ?

Comment: don't think so.. well you gotta not cash locally but I don't think you do ;) -- so no :/

Comment: @Daij-Djan - As I am not specifying anything about cache policy in my request the default *NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy* will be the behaviour...so caching will happen.

Comment: Yes I'd assume that's fine but you could disable it to be sure

Comment: @Daij-Djan - Am I safe to assume disabling caching on the request would solve the inconsistency ?

Comment: I hadn't considered that the default caching would be a problem but maybe it would help to disable it

Answer (score 19):

I've encountered the same problem. I've discovered that it's because of `cachePolicy`. You need to set it as follows:

```
request.cachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```

And you will be OK

Comment: This should be marked as an answer. Brilliant catch!

Comment: This worked for me. Could you mark this as the solution?

Comment: This saved me hours of tracing why S3 was ignoring my If-None-Match header, thanks!!!

Comment: Literally spent 2 weeks looking for this. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

CachePolicy naming convention is confusing and better yet it actually does not implement some of them...

This article explains them well. http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Also, if you let the Cache Policy to use `UseProtocolCachePolicy` then your NSURLSession will receive Status code `200` with response generated from Cache.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the cache policy 'useProtocolCachePolicy', 'returnCacheDataElseLoad' or 'returnCacheDataDontLoad'.

You can use any other policy then above one. Preferably 'reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData'.

Answer (score 0):

.reloadRevalidatingCacheData was introduced recently which sounds a bit more efficient than the reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData way of the yore