# Why Alamofire GET 'If-None-Match' does not work?

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

For example i have the following code:

```
let headers = ["If-None-Match": etag, "Authorization": "Token token=\(apiKey)"]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(AppSettings.ApiURL)/v1/users/", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

    guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {return}
    print("status code: \(statusCode)")
}
```

And i get the `status code: 200` every time, instead of `304`. The same request with curl or postman is returned `304 status code`. I don't know where is mistake. Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: What do you get from `debutPrint(request)`?

Comment: Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/a/31614237/669586

Comment: I've solved this problem in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608051/etag-and-if-none-match-http-headers-are-not-working/